# Dao is null while using Dagger2

Tags: java, android, android-room, dagger-2

When i call DAO in presenter, it returns null and causes NPE.
Some code here:
DAO class

```
@Dao
public interface ElementsDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM   `elements`")
    Flowable<List<Elements>> getAll();

    @Insert
    Maybe<Long> insert(Elements element);...
}
```

modules classes:

```
@Module
public class DatabaseModule {

    private AppDatabase appDatabase;
    public DatabaseModule(Application mApplication){
        appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(mApplication, AppDatabase.class,"dbWarehouse")
                .setJournalMode(RoomDatabase.JournalMode.TRUNCATE)
                .build();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public AppDatabase provideDatabase(){
        return appDatabase;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    ElementsDao providesElementsDao(AppDatabase appDatabase){
        return appDatabase.getElementsDao();
    }
}

@Module
public class AppModule {
    Application mApplication;

    public AppModule(Application application){
        mApplication = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Application providesApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }
}
```

Component class

```
@Singleton
@Component(dependencies = {},modules = {AppModule.class, DatabaseModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
    void inject(ElementsActivity elementsActivity);
    void inject(ActivityElementsPresenter activityElementsPresenter);

    ElementsDao elementsDao();

    AppDatabase appDatabase();

    Application application();
}
```

App class (declared in manifest)

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static AppComponent appComponent;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        initDagger();
    }
    private void initDagger(){
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .databaseModule(new DatabaseModule(this))
                .build();
    }

    public static AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        return appComponent;
    }
}
```

And presenter

```
@InjectViewState
public class ActivityElementsPresenter extends MvpPresenter<ActivityElementsView> {
    @Inject
    ElementsDao elementsDao;

    public void addElement(Elements element){
        elementsDao.insert(element).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())...
```

**UPDATE**
AppDatabase class

```
@Database(entities = {Elements.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters({Converters.class})
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract ElementsDao getElementsDao();
    //...
}
```

While debuging i setted a point in presenter and saw that dao isn't initialized
[elementsDao](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB5Eo.png)
Trying to use something like `App.getAppComponent().elementsDao();` but it inst works too.

Comment: can you add code of `AppDatabase` class

Comment: not here,add to your question, here it's not readable.

Comment: @rahat sorry, question updated

Comment: How are you getting an instance of `ActivityElementsPresenter`?

Comment: can you add the code of `MvpPresenter`, is `MvpPresenter` is the base class for all presenter?

Comment: @rahat MvpPresenter is the base class of [Moxy](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy) library, helps to use MVP

Comment: then how you create instance of presenter?

Comment: @rahat leading the documentation, i uses anotation - `@InjectPresenter ActivityElementsPresenter activityElementsPresenter;` Thats fine, presenter is initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it this way,

```
@InjectViewState
public class ActivityElementsPresenter extends MvpPresenter<ActivityElementsView> {
    @Inject
    ElementsDao elementsDao;

    public ActivityElementsPresenter(){
       App.getAppComponent().inject(this);//calling the dagger's injector to inject dependency.
    }

    public void addElement(Elements element){
        elementsDao.insert(element).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())...
    }
}
```

Then in

```
@Singleton
@Component(dependencies = {},modules = {AppModule.class, DatabaseModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
    void inject(ElementsActivity elementsActivity);
    void inject(ActivityElementsPresenter activityElementsPresenter);//will inject dependency to ActivityElementsPresenter.  
}
```

Comment: Now for every presenter, you have to add one abstract method to the AppComponent and call the `inject` method in the constructor.

Comment: If you use a BasePresenter Pattern then Injection will be easier for you.